# Android java code stopping on first for loop

Tags: java, android, if-statement, for-loop

I have 2 Arraylists, one for phones and other for contacts,what I'm trying to do is show the contents as it comes from the API, if the client has contacts and phones to show it will show, but if the client has contacts and no phones it will show nothing, what am I missing here? I have to show the contacts even if the client has no phones and vice versa

```
      for (int i = 0; i < tel.size(); i++) {

            if(tel.size() > 0) {


            TextView TituloTelefone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TelefoneTitulo);
            View DivisorTelefone = findViewById(R.id.ViewTelefone);
            TituloTelefone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DivisorTelefone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.telefones, null);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.telefone);
            TextView tipoTelefone = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tipoTelefone);

            tv.setText("0" + tel.get(i).getNumero().replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));


        }

    }



        for (int j = 0; j < contato.size(); j++) {

            if(contato.size() > 0) {

            TextView TituloContato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contatoTitulo);
            TituloContato.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            LayoutInflater inflaterContato = getLayoutInflater();
            View viContato = inflaterContato.inflate(R.layout.contatos, null);
            final TextView tvContato = (TextView) viContato.findViewById(R.id.contatos);
            final TextView id = (TextView) viContato.findViewById(R.id.IDcontato);

            id.setText(String.valueOf(contato.get(j).getId_rm()));

            String mString = contato.get(j).getNome();

            String contatoString = mString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + mString.substring(1);

            tvContato.setText(contatoString);


        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand quite well your question... but what is `tel.size()` and `contato.size()` value?

Comment: @dwnz private `List<TelefoneModel> tel = new ArrayList<TelefoneModel>();
    private List<ContatoClienteModel> contato = new ArrayList<ContatoClienteModel>();`

Comment: I mean, what is the size of both `ArrayList` while doing the for loop? Is it higher than 1? You should debug it, it shouldn't be difficult to find out your problem.

Comment: @dwnz As the content is coming from an API, sometimes the size change, if the client has no phones so the Arraylist will be 0

Comment: Try to manually debug it and see if you can spot the problem. From your information and your code I can't see what is wrong there.

Comment: Your `for` looks start with checking `0 < list.size()`. Then, your `if` statements inside check if the size() > 0.

For the first loop, if `tel.size()` is `null`, then `i` (which is 0) is not less then 0 or null, so the for loop evaluates as false. It may help to try printing the .size() values before the for loop, to ensure contato.size() != null or 0

Comment: @CreationEdge, Just solved my problem, thank you for your patience

Comment: @jgandroid You're welcome. It was hard to compose an answer on my tablet, so I'm glad a comment with failed autocorrects and inconsistent formatting helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I just had to check if the array was not null, like this:

```
        if(tel != null) {
           for (int i = 0; i < tel.size(); i++) {




            TextView TituloTelefone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TelefoneTitulo);
            View DivisorTelefone = findViewById(R.id.ViewTelefone);
            TituloTelefone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DivisorTelefone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.telefones, null);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.telefone);
            TextView tipoTelefone = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tipoTelefone);

            tv.setText("0" + tel.get(i).getNumero().replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));


        }

    }
```